# Not able to send POST request using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to send `POST` request using javascript. below is the code snippet-

```
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
       var uid = i;
       var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
       var params = 'uid='+uid;
       http.open('POST','/home/index.php', true);

       http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
       http.setRequestHeader('Content-length', params.length);
/*    
       http.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
             continue;
          }
       }
*/
       http.send(params);
    }
```

After running the script from firebug, no request is being sent.
[image]

Where is the error?

Answer (score 0):

You have an illegal `continue` statement. You can only use `continue` in loops, not as a way to break out of a function. Try `return` instead.

Comment: Hey, i commented the complete `http.onreadystatechange` function. Firebug is showing `undefined`. Screenshot is attached in the question.